# Do not trigger form.$invalid on first load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-directive, angularjs-forms

Having such form

```
    <div ng-controller="FormController as f_ctrl">
    <form ng-submit="f_ctrl.submit()" name="myForm">
    <input type="text" ng-model="f_ctrl.user.username"
            required
            ng-minlength="4"/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="f_ctrl.user.password"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">
    </form>
</div>
```

and such controller

```
    .controller('FormController', [function() {
    var self = this;

    self.submit = function() {
        console.log('User submitted form with ' + self.user.username)
    }
}]);
```

I have a problem: when page first loads it immediately shows red border on  username field, even before I start typing anything.
I need to highlight invalid fields only after first submission. Can this be done using `form.$invalid` ?

Comment: If it is firefox only problem, angular recently fixed it on master

Answer (score 3):

You have to use $pristine for that. It is true when form controller is not changed. so when you change textbox data its comes false.

Small example for you.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.password.$invalid && !userForm.password.$pristine }">
    <input id="passAnime" type="password" name="password" ng-model="user.password" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="Password" tabindex="5" ng-maxlength="25" ng-minlength="6" required>

    <span ng-show="userForm.password.$dirty && userForm.password.$invalid">
        <p ng-show="userForm.password.$error.required" class="error-messages">
             Your password is required.
        </p>
        <p ng-show="userForm.password.$error.minlength" class="error-messages">
            Your password is too short. Minimum 6 chars.
        </p>
        <p ng-show="userForm.password.$error.maxlength" class="error-messages">
            Your password is too long. Maximum 25 chars. 
        </p>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean I need add `ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.password.$invalid && !userForm.password.$pristine }"` for every form field that I have? Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: Yah we have to made for every controller which you want to check for validation

Comment: So if I had form with 50 fields, I need for each of those fields put such line
`ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.field_name.$invalid && !userForm.field_name.$pristine }"` ?

Comment: No, but if you have to do dynamically then you can create whole form dynamically in controller and inject form to html

Comment: What I want is not to have red border around fields when form loads and put this border only when user starts filling in the form

Answer (score 1):

Angular has [helpers](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation#angular-form-properties-$valid,-$invalid,-$pristine,-$dirty) that tell you if the form (or form field) is `$dirty` (user has typed something) or if the form is `$touched` (the blur event has been triggered on the input). See [this](http://codepen.io/sevilayha/pen/xFcdI) demo.

> I need to highlight invalid fields only after first submission.

Unfortunately, Angular doesn't support that. But you could implement it yourself rather easily:

**Controller**

```
function FormController() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.submitAttempted = false;
  vm.submit = function(isValid) {
    if (isValid) {
      // do stuff
    }
    else {
      vm.submitAttempted = true;
    }
  };
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller='FormController as vm'>
    <form name='fooForm' ng-submit='vm.submit(fooForm.$valid)' novalidate>
      <label>Username</label>
      <input 
        name='username' 
        type='text' 
        ng-model='vm.user.username'
        required
        ng-minlength='4'
        ng-class="{'invalid': vm.submitAttempted && fooForm.username.$invalid}">
      <br /><br />
      <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.invalid {
  border-color: red;
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpJmBM)

---

> I have a problem: when page first loads it immediately shows red border on username field, even before I start typing anything.

That's probably because you have the following CSS class:

```
.ng-invalid {
  border-color: red;
}
```

Angular will always apply the `ng-invalid` class to fields that are invalid, and there's nothing you could do about that. So if you don't *always* want invalid fields to have a red border, you can't use that class and you should do it in a way similar to what I proposed above.

---

Also, check out [ngMessages](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation-with-ngmessages).

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the default styling on the input field that is adding the red border by default, by adding the following CSS:

```
input:required {
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Then if you want to highlight the field when the form is submitted, you will need to ensure that the form and form fields have relevant name attributes. Doing this will allow you to check if the field is valid or not and apply a class to your text field when it is invalid:

```
<input type="text" name="username" ng-class="{ 'invalid-field' : f_ctrl.myForm.username.$invalid && !f_ctrl.myForm.username.$pristine }" required />
```

**f_ctrl.myForm** and **f_ctrl.myform.username** will have additional properties that you can use/check to determine if the form or fields are invalid or not, or if they have been modified at any point (e.g. f_ctrl.myform.username.$dirty). You should be able to view these properties on your page by adding the follow HTML:

```
<div>
    <pre>{{f_ctrl.myForm | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

Or, you could output **self.myForm** to the console from your controller to view it's properties

```
console.log(self.myForm);
```